# .htaccess forward 'www.w.' to 'www.'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a weird issue where Google is indexing several of my site's pages as 'www.w.example.com' which is causing issues with my security certificate.

While I'm looking for a solution, I'd like to redirect this using .htaccess but I can't seem to get it to work.

Currently I have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)www\.w\.(.*)$/$ https://www.$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to work..

I have multiple domains for this site so ideally it needs to redirect to the correct domain e.g. https://www.example1.com or https://www.example2.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `RewriteCond` for matching host name:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.w\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

However you might still get SSL cert warning because cert negotiation happens before `mod_rewrite` rules are invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know of any way I can just redirect rather than rewrite?

Comment: This is indeed `redirect`. Anytime `R` flag is used OR when `http://` is used in target URI it is redirect not a rewrite.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've tried your code but it still isn't redirecting :-/

Comment: Yep, this is the first rule in the file. I'm entering `https://www.w.example.com/ `to test it

Comment: To verify this .htaccess is being invoked enter some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess`  and then open `https://www.w.example.com/`.  Check if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not ?

Comment: OK - it wasn't being invoked as I am forwarding from another .htaccess file. I tried it in there, though, and you were right that I would still be getting certificate warnings :( looks like I'll have to sort the issue with Google! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yes cert warning would be there but if you ignore the warning then above redirect will take place.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad SEO practice to have the same content available on more than 1 URLs.

You need to decide on the best URL you would like to use and then do a 301 redirect of the others to it.

Comment: I completely agree - I literally just realised that I wanted to redirect rather than rewrite.

Comment: Oh, if you are referring to the multiple domains, they are branded to different clients so I need to have the content available on different URLs in this case.